# 404 on jQuery AJAX request in Spring boot

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I have recently created a Spring boot project and am trying to work with jQuery AJAX to get data from Controller in Spring. It returns 404 for some reason.

My controller

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadHome() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/getMajors", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ArrayList<String> getMajors(){
        ArrayList<String> majors = new ArrayList<>();
        majors.add("Computers");
        majors.add("Physics");
        return majors;
    }

}
```

The first method was to load the home page `index.html` the second was the method that maps to AJAX request.

My jQuery AJAX Request

```
$.ajax({
    type:"get",
    url:"/getMajors",
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Please tell me why I'm getting a 404 here. TIA.

Edit: This app was created in Springboot. Standard config with web, dev-tools packages - from spring initializer.

Comment: do you have any server.context implemented?

Comment: are you able to get a response if you hit `localhost:8080/getMajors` in your browser?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are missing two things. One is the context name which usually is the name of the project or the war file deployed to the server, unless you are providing another context in web.xml. A sample servlet mapping from web.xml file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So when your ajax call hits `/getMajors` it usually points to "`localhost:port/getMajors`" instead of say "`localhost:port/sampleproj/getMajors`" .You are missing the context there.

So your method needs to look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMajors", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ArrayList<String> getMajors(){
        ArrayList<String> majors = new ArrayList<>();
        majors.add("Computers");
        majors.add("Physics");
        return majors;
}
```

One good method to debug these is to see the developer console(Chrome) for request response information.

Happy Coding!

**Edit 1**: removing @ResponseBody from method as the class is annotated with @RestController. But my statement stands correct in case the class is annotated with @Controller.

Comment: you dont need `@ResponseBody` if your class is annotated as `@RestController`. You can return every datatype you wish, it must not be String. And you just need a context if you really implemented one.

Comment: @Patrick is right, the reason I used `RestController` is to remove additional declarations of `ResponseBody`-s

Comment: ok. I guess i overlooked the RestController annotation. Will modify answer accordingly. but even so I think context mapping is still important. @Kalyan did you check that?